# Angular Basic ng-bind and ng-click won't work

Tags: html, angularjs, scope, addition, subtraction

I'm an angular beginner and it does not seem to respond to me. I'm trying to to a simple ng-click to add and subtract to a counter. I get his error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=FirstController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined...
```

this is index.html:

controller.js:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
     $scope.word = "ever";
     $scope.counter = 0;
     $scope.add = function(amount) { 
      $scope.counter += amount; 
     };
     $scope.subtract = function(amount) {
      $scope.counter -= amount; 
     };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <title>Simple App</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="FirstController">
    <h4>The simplest adding machine ever</h4>
    <button ng-click="add(1)" class="button">Add</button>
    <a ng-click="subtract(1)" class="button alert">Subtract</a>
    <h4>Current count: {{ counter }}</h4>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try this, change `<html ng-app>` to `<html ng-app="app">`

Comment: `ng-app` is kinda wrong placed. It should be in (in most of the cases) `ng-app="myApp"` and `ng-controller="myController"` in the body tag. Check for tutorials for Angular in google and try copy step by step every row of code. You will get it in no time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to specify what app you use , try the following code :

```
  <html ng-app="app">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this it seems your missing the ng-app inclusion in the html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.1" data-semver="1.3.1" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="test">
    <div trans-directive></div>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
   <div ng-controller="trans">
      <h4>The simplest adding machine ever</h4>
      <button ng-click="add(1)" class="button">Add</button>
      <button ng-click="subtract(1)" class="button alert">Subtract</button>
      <h4>Current count: {{ counter }}</h4>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
var app = angular.module("test",[]);
app.controller('trans',function($scope){
  $scope.name = 'amruth';
  $scope.word = "ever";
  $scope.counter = 0;
  $scope.add = function(amount) { 
    $scope.counter += amount; 
  };
  $scope.subtract = function(amount) {
    $scope.counter -= amount; 
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/khFwKUvKkruhMa5CYtRt?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code that works: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6uNhjsUNQ3TuSIhP6qI?p=preview).

Changes required :

- `ng-app` should have a value assigned to it.
- add `ng-app` to the body tag, as your angular script is in the head tag, html will not recognize angular
- Include your controller.js after the angular but before the script code.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('FirstController',function($scope) {
  $scope.word = "ever";
  $scope.counter = 0;
  $scope.add = function(amount) {
    $scope.counter += amount;
  };
  $scope.subtract = function(amount) {
    $scope.counter -= amount;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple App</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.1" data-semver="1.3.1" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="FirstController">
    <h4>The simplest adding machine ever</h4>
    <button ng-click="add(1)" class="button">Add</button>
    <a ng-click="subtract(1)" class="button alert">Subtract</a>
    <h4>Current count: {{ counter }}</h4>
  </div>

  {{6+2}}


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. modify html file

Here is solution for your problem.Add following line inside your html code

    <html ng-app='app'>
inside <head> tag add script : <script  src="app.js"></script>

 2. modify controller.js

    app.controller('FirstController',function($scope){});
Error occured because you added extra space between "'FirstController'," and "function($scope){})"
```